# How to create multiple ajax calls in jQuery in more efficient and useful way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have these 3 links in my code:

```
<ul>
<li><a id="link1" href="#">link 1</a></li>
<li><a id="link2" href="#">link 2</a></li>
<li><a id="link3" href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is how I write the ajax request for each link (as you can see the same code is multiple 3 times for each link - and I want to know how to avoid that)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#link1").click(function() {
        $.get("anothertest.php?q=1", function(data){
            $("#phpTestAlon").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("a#link2").click(function() {
        $.get("anothertest.php?q=2", function(data){
            $("#phpTestAlon").html(data);
        });
    });
    });
    $("a#link3").click(function() {
        $.get("anothertest.php?q=3", function(data){
            $("#phpTestAlon").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

What is the way to create this code but without the multiple duplications to make it more efficient? Is there a way to write it like this?:

$.get("anothertest.php?q=" + **theIDofTheElement**, function(data){

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `data-id` attribute to your link and use one piece of JS:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="link1" href="#" data-id="1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="#" data-id="2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link3" href="#" data-id="3">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$("ul li a").click(function() {
    var idToSend = $(this).data('id');

    $.get("anothertest.php?q=" + idToSend, function(data){
        $("#phpTestAlon").html(data);
    });
});
```

This example uses `data-id`, but you could use any attribute you wanted, including `id=""`. Another sensible option would be `rel=""`.

Notice the selector has changed to `ul li a` so as to capture all `<a>` clicks in one event.

Comment: Why not just put the url in `href` and not use any `data-*`?

Comment: @AmirRaminfar Because then the browser thinks the `<a>` points to `http://thedomain/1` if we have `href="1"`; it treats it as a normal link.

Comment: Not not at all what I mean. Look at my answer. I would put the whole url in the href like so `href="anothertest.php?q=2"`. Less code. Better usability. Still works if js is disabled. Every body is happy.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar Because then the link would just redirect to a new page. The OP is asking about AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$("ul li a").click(function() {
        e.preventDefault()
        $.get(this.href, function(data){
            $("#phpTestAlon").html(data);
        });
    });
```

With this HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a id="link1" href="anothertest.php?q=1">link 1</a></li>
<li><a id="link2" href="anothertest.php?q=2">link 2</a></li>
<li><a id="link3" href="anothertest.php?q=3">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

It is important that this solution also works if javascript is disabled. `return false` will make sure if js is enabled to not actually go to a different page. But if js was disabled, then the user would just go to whatever linked they clicked on.

Comment: `return false` is bad. Why aren't you using `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: [It's bad](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/), and it isn't; I don't see `e.preventDefault()` anyehere in your answer.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with that answer. I prefer have jQuery cancel the event instead of me.

Comment: Using `e.preventDefault()`, jQuery _does_ cancel the event for you. What do you mean by `have jQuery cancel the event instead of me`? **Edit:** It doesn't cancel the event; the code inside the handler still executes, it just stops the _default_ behaviour of the event.

Comment: Oh Wait, `e.preventDefault()` is a jquery api call. Ok now I agree with you. :) To explain more, I was trying to say that if `preventDefault` was javascript and not jquery api, I wouldn't use it because I prefer jQuery's well tested api.

Comment: That makes sense, but standard JavaScript is probably much more tested than jQuery, although cross-platform wise it isn't. `e.preventDefault()` is actually a JS (not jQuery) function, as can be seen [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault).

Comment: This page http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ makes me think it is part of jQuery? But you are right I meant cross-browser tested. Not actual js tested.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5566/discussion-between-amir-raminfar-and-jamwaffles)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var  theIDofTheElement = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d$/)[0];
```

Comment: This is a solution to the problem the OP is describing, but it's better to solve the _cause_ of the problem, than work around the problem itself. No disrespect, just some friendly advice :-)